# Open / close tor private window using ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, tor

I have installed [Tor Browser on ubuntu](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tor-browser-on-ubuntu-18-04/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20start%20the%20Tor,Browser%20and%20all%20other%20dependencies.). when I run `torbrowser-launcher` it does open tor. But I want to open a website directly in tor private window using ubuntu terminal when I enter the command. and would be great to know how to quit it from command line. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. To open an URL in a browser from the command line, consult the manual of the browser. Usually, it is sufficient to include the URL after the command.
2. To close a certain process in the terminal after it has launched, you can use the `kill` command, with the `pid` of the process as argument.

   The `pid` of a process is available in the shell right after running the command in the variable `$!`. Thus, launch your browser then save `$!` into another variable for later use within the same shell, or to a file if you want it also available in another shell.